# Higher resolution on a complex plot

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm trying to program the complex zeta-function: `ComplexPlot[Zeta[s],{s,-40-40I,40+40I}]`. The problem is that if I convert it into an image and then save it, the resolution is quite low. How can I higher the resolution of a complex plot?

Comment: You could try increasing the setting of `RasterSize`.

Comment: Try to use the option `PlotPoints->100` and play with the number of points.

Comment: `Export[“filepath/pic.png”, plt, ImageResolution -> 300]` might help.

Comment: To fill two white holes at corners of the plot, use `ComplexPlot[Zeta[s], {s, -40 - 4 I, 40 + 4 I}, 
 ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None}]` which works well. `PlotPoints->100` does not help. In the right half-plane the $\zeta$-function is close to $1$, e.g. `Zeta[20. + 10.*I]` equals `1. - 5.75563*10^-7 I`, so that halfplane is colored in red.

Comment: I'd like to explain these wihite holes: the modulus of the $\zeta$-function is very big there, e.g. `Zeta[-30. + 30.*I]` equals `-2.65265*10^22 - 1.76156*10^22 I`. I don't find that behavior of `ComplexPlot` to be  buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `ComplexPlot[Zeta[s],{s,-40-40I,40+40I},PlotPoints->100]` produces an incomplete plot:
[image]

In order to improve the plot, use `ComplexPlot[Zeta[s], {s, -40 - 40 I, 40 + 40 I},   ColorFunction -> {Hue[#8 + 0.5] &, None},PlotPoints->100]`

which works well.

[image]

The reason is a big range of the values of the `Zeta` there:  `Zeta[-30. + 30.*I]` equals `-2.65265*10^22 - 1.76156*10^22 I` and `Zeta[20. + 20.*I]` equals `1. - 9.18047*10^-7 I`.  In the right half-plane the `Zeta`-function is close to 1 so that half-plane is colored in red. For a better export (The original is fine.) use an advice of @MassDefect.